# ¿Por qué los infinitivos de los verbos son siempre palabras agudas?

Tags: gramática, verbos, acentuación

Hoy me di cuenta de que todos los infinitivos de los verbos son palabras agudas:

- co**mer**
- be**ber**
- dige**rir**
- repercu**tir**
- endio**sar**
- o**ír**
- **ser**
- ... <sub>bueno, podría poner tantos ejemplos como verbos hay en el diccionario.</sub>

En otros idiomas no es así (en catalán decimos ***có***rrer para correr, sin ir más lejos).

¿Existe algún motivo para esto?

Comment: Creo que la respuesta puede ser tan simple como que los verbos suelen provenir del latín, sólo que entonces acababan con una -e extra que en español se ha perdido, pero que en otros idiomas se mantiene, como en el italiano. Dichas palabras eran llanas, la posición dominante del acento en nuestro idioma, pero al perder la última -e el acento se mantuvo en su sitio convirtiendo las palabras en agudas.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Uhms, interesante. ¿Todos, todos los verbos vienen del latín?

Comment: Sin embargo, algunos, que en catalán ahora son graves (o en italiano esdrújulos), eran esdrújulos en latín, como _cúrrere_ (> correr) o _créscere_ (> crecer).

Comment: Obviamente todos no, ahí tienes [tuitear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asr6h3K). Sin embargo, la inmensa mayoría diría que sí. De la lista que tú has puesto arriba, el único que es una construcción moderna sería _endiosar_, el resto vienen directos del latín. Interesante, en todo caso, el aporte de @angus, el cual desconocía. Posiblemente como el acento en la mayoría de los verbos estaba en la última sílaba (tras perderse la última -e), por homogeneidad todos los acentos se fueron trasladando hacia esta sílaba.

Comment: Creo (con todo respeto) que esta pregunta es de las que se puede responder "_es así porque así es_". Las desinencias verbales españolas incluyen sistemáticamente la acentuación (exceptuando los verbos irregulares). Que otros idiomas hagan otras cosas se debe a que son otros idiomas. Caprichos históricos de la comunidad lingüística estabilizaron una regla u otra. Si no, habría un solo idioma.

Comment: @Rodrigo interesante punto este de que la desinencia siempre incluye la acentuación, no había caído en ello. Nótese que la mía es una pregunta del tipo _¿por qué..._ y no _¿¡por qué..._ irado :) Es decir, de por qué la lengua castellana creció en este sentido y no en otro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vayamos por partes.

Comencemos con que el 70% del léxico del español proviene del latín, porcentaje que sube hasta el 85% si nos ceñimos al vocabulario de uso cotidiano. Y me atrevería a decir que si pensamos solamente en los verbos, el porcentaje es aun más alto.

En latín existían cuatro declinaciones posibles para los verbos (excluyendo las formas mixtas):

1. Verbos con infinitivo acabado en -are.
2. Verbos con infinitivo acabado en -ere, con la primera *e* larga.
3. Verbos con infinitivo acabado en -ere, con la primera *e* corta.
4. Verbos con infinitivo acabado en -ire.

En latín existían 10 vocales: las versiones largas y cortas de nuestras cinco vocales. Los infinitivos de la segunda declinación eran llanos porque en la terminación tenían una *e* larga, mientras que los de la tercera declinación eran esdrújulos, al tener la *e* corta y pasar el acento a la sílaba anterior. En las declinaciones primera y cuarta, los infinitivos eran también llanos al ser largas la *a* y la *i* de las terminaciones.

Posteriormente, en el [latín vulgar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lat%C3%ADn_vulgar) que sucedió al latín clásico se produjo por una parte la pérdida de muchas vocales átonas, entre las que se incluyeron las terminaciones de los verbos. Y por otra parte se produjo una fusión de las declinaciones verbales:

1. La primera declinación del latín vulgar corresponde con la primera del clásico.
2. La segunda declinación del latín vulgar se quedó con una parte de los verbos de la segunda y tercera del clásico.
3. La tercera declinación del latín vulgar se quedó con la cuarta del clásico más el resto de verbos de la segunda y tercera (por ejemplo, *dicere* pasó a ser *dezir*).

El proceso de eliminación de vocales hizo que el acento pasara a la última sílaba en la mayoría de los infinitivos (al pasar a acabar todos en *-ar*, *-er*, *-ir*), y la fusión entre la segunda y tercera formas de declinar del latín clásico hizo que cuando apareció el [castellano medieval](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_medieval) (allá por el siglo IX), ya todos los verbos eran agudos en el infinitivo.

Ahora bien, este proceso de fusión debió de tener lugar de distintas formas según la región. Se ve que en catalán se mantuvo la posición de la sílaba tónica en el infinitivo de algunos verbos (seguramente la mayoría acabados en *-e*). ¿Por qué el castellano tuvo esta fusión definitiva de la segunda declinación, mientras que el catalán no? Posiblemente tenga que ver con lo que comentamos al principio de las vocales largas y cortas. En castellano las vocales se redujeron a cinco, eliminando la distinción entre vocales largas y cortas, con lo que ya no tenía sentido distinguir entre verbos acabados en *-er* agudos y llanos. En cambio, en catalán sí que se mantuvo esa distinción en algunas vocales, como la *e* y la *o*, y se pudo mantener la distinción entre las dos declinaciones (acabados en *-er* llanos, como *témer* y *córrer*, conjugación IIa del catalán, y acabados en *-re* llanos porque perdieron la vocal tónica, como *perdre*, conjugación IIb del catalán).

Reconozco que parte de lo aquí expresado son suposiciones mías (y admito además mi alto grado de desconocimiento del catalán), dado que no he encontrado textos que traten el tema en profundidad. Aun así, espero que la explicación te encaje.

Comment: Pues me gustan mucho las suposiciones y agradezco el tiempo dedicado a explicarlas :) Como complemento, Rodrigo escribió en los comentarios sobre el hecho de que en castellano la desinencia es la que incluye la acentuación.