# Why Spanish has only three terminations for the infinitive of verbs?

Tags: etimología, verbos, infinitivo

In Spanish, the infinitive of a verb always ends with one of these three terminations

- -ar (amar, llorar, buscar)
- -er (comer, saber, leer)
- -ir (reir, vivir, servir)

What is the reason that there are only these three? Why not having `-or` or `-ur` terminations, or something completely different?

Why there are only these three terminations for the infinitive of verbs in Spanish?

Comment: Yo diría que aquí está la respuesta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18253/14069